# ESP8266 using EEPROM to store a value of 100,000

Tags: eeprom

I'm using Wemos mini in my project. I wish to store a Boolean value in cell #0, which changes every boot.

Since writing to EEPROM is limited to roughly 100,000 cycles - I want to store in cell #1 the amount of writing cycles done so far, so when reaching 100,000 , value will be stored in cell#2 and writing cycles will be stored in cell#3 and so on.

Reading and writing using `#include <EEPROM.h>` is done as needed, but since each cell can store a byte, it can only reach 255.

My question is how to store a value of 10^6 (except of convert it to a*2^0 + b*2^1 + c*2^2 + d*2^3....).

Guy

**EDIT1**

Part or relevant code:

```
void setup() {
        Serial.begin(9600);
        Serial.println("BEGIN:");
        if (HARD_REBOOT) {
                EEPROM.begin(1024);
        }
        if (HARD_REBOOT) {
                EEPROM.write(0,100000);
                EEPROM.commit();
                delay(50);
                Serial.print("value in flash: ");
                Serial.println(EEPROM.read(0));
        }
}
```

and its output:

```
Ȥl⸮⸮BGS[⸮<b8ɗ⸮BEGIN:
22:40:58.732 -> value in flash: 160
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98432/discussion-on-question-by-guy-d-esp8266-using-eeprom-to-store-a-value-of-100-0).

Answer (score 2):

The esp doesn't have an eeprom, but emulates it in its flash. Therefore 100.000 cylces will not apply, it's more like 10.000 cycles for flash.

The easiest way to prepare a datatype to be stored as bytes is to use [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) like follows:

```
union Converter{
  uint32_t ui32;
  byte eeprom_bytes[4];
}convert;

void convert_for_eeprom (uint32_t your_number) {
  convert.ui32=your_number;
  // convert.eeprom_bytes contains the 4-byte represenstation of your number, write those to eeprom
}

uint32_t convert_from_eeprom () {
  // read four bytes from eeprom and assign those to convert.eeprom_bytes
  return convert.ui32;
}
```

Note that this isn't a type conversion and the value of convert.eeprom_bytes are not meant to be processed, as they are simply interpreted as if they were a four-byte array, indeed those bytes contain "dumb" values. This way you can "convert" **any datatype** for byte-wise storage and read-back respectively.

Another option to convert a 32 bit integer to 4 bytes is by using bit-wise operations:

```
uint32_t your_number=100000;
byte b1=your_number;
byte b2=your_number>>8;
byte b3=your_number>>16;
byte b4=your_number>>24;
```

But this only makes sense for integers and I suggest taking a look at `union`.

Comment: `EEPROM.put()` can write any type. that is the easiest  way

Answer (score 2):

to save any variable to EEPROM use [`EEPROM.put()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROMPut), to read it use `EEPROM.get()`. example

`EEPROM.put(EEPROM_COUNT_ADDR, count);`

`EEPROM.get(EEPROM_COUNT_ADDR, count);`

On esp8266 EEPROM is emulated in flash and there **the whole page wears out**. [The EEPROM library](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html#eeprom) of esp8266 does what can be done to protect the flash pages used for EEPROM emulation.

Comment: But still can use ‘put’ and ‘get’?

Comment: yes. the esp8266 EEPROM library has put() and get() too.

Comment: substitute `write` in `put`, was OK, but when using `get` yielded : 
`error: no matching function for call to 'EEPROMClass::get(int)'
                 Serial.println(EEPROM.get(0));`

Comment: `EEPROM.get(EEPROM_COUNT_ADDR, count);` ! Use second parameter for a variable to be filled.

Comment: @Guy.D, does it work?